# Concatenate multiple trimmed videos FFmpeg

Tags: bash, scripts, video, ffmpeg

I am a rooky in FFmpeg and I am trying to concatenate multiple videos that must be trimmed into a new video, the command that I am trying to use is:

```
ffmpeg -i 00042.mp4 -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:03 -i 00040.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:02 -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 output.mp4
```

The code works fine, but is concatenating and addit to "output.mp4" only for the last video inputted.

Do you have any suggetion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last `-to` is trimming the *output* file.

Options for each input file must be *before* each `-i`, so change:

```
ffmpeg -i 00042.mp4 -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:03 -i 00040.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:02 -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 output.mp4
```

to:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:03 -i 00042.mp4 -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:02 -i 00040.mp4  -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much!